# Is it possible to use C++ classes in nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js

I have written some classes in C++. I have used OOP. Now I want to use this classes in nodejs. I think it can be done in this ways:

1. Creating objects of C++ classes in nodejs and calling their methods.
2. Calling compiled c++ codes, and get outputs.
3. Interacting with running compiled C++ programs (IPC like technology).
4. Another way you prefer.

Which of these solutions is feasible?

Note: I have seen nodejs-ffi module, but it seems to use built-in methods only. Is that true?

Lets assume that I have written this:

```
namespace Math
{
    class Aljebra
    {
        int Abs(int);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you have checked out nodejs documentation on C/C++ addons. http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: Yes, I found ffi but it doesn't support OOP, I think.

Comment: If you mean writing add-on for every class I want to use in nodejs, It is not what I want. But is It the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in all the ways you think of.

1. You need to create binding of your C++ classes to Nodejs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js) or [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nsm.nikhil/writing-native-bindings-to-nodejs-in-c) and [here](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#templates). If performance are not negligible, you might find issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12197292/142039). Anyways, this is the fastest method.
2. Calling codes? I always call a functions, but if you wonder how to use modules like nodejs-ffi it's a big pain to use them with C++. All function names are mangled in C++, which means that your `Math::Aljebra::Abs` might actually be called `_ZN4Math7Aljebra3AbsEi` and that depends on the compiler you use. If your library contain mostly `extern "C"` function,  usable.
3. There are many libraries for doing that. I prefer [DBus](https://github.com/Motorola-Mobility/node-dbus). You can use it to communicate with many system daemons. Of course if you want to use it with your C++ code you need to write a DBus service to communicate to.
4. That depend. If you are not able to compile, just use existing library, second solution might be the only one. If there is a need to communicate many nodejs instances to each other within your C++ library, third solution might be better.

Comment: Great help! but this means that no rapid solution is built in nodejs itself. If it is true, then I must do more job. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've used Node.js and C++ a decent amount seperately - I spose I could see Node.js as being the server-side language and C++ being the client-side in a very conventional way. This, however, sort of voids a lot of the power of Node.js as a client-side language, which is one of the "hotter" features of the language - that it can do both.

Additionally, I'm not sure of the support C++ has for client-side web development stuff. It's such a robust language, I'm sure it's possible... but I think by the time you figure out how to implement the C++ with Node.js, you could've just re-written the functions you want to call in C++ in Node.js or some other more suitable language.

Comment: What do you mean about suitable? Is there any alternative language to do that?

Comment: I mean that C++ is not a conventional client-side language for web applications; the code you want to run in C++, it may be a less time-consuming effort to just transcribe it to a conventional client-side language.

Comment: First, nodejs isn't the client side language, javascript is. What popular frameworks like derbyjs, meteor, towerjs do is that they serialize the nodejs code, send it to client and evaluate it on client. Any code that uses nodejs api which interacts with system resources will not work on client. There is a way however to run native code on client. Wrapping them into a plugin. I don't know how feasible it is to generate such code on the fly. Secondly it poses security threats. A user should not ideally allow any plugin to run which doesn't come from trustable sources.